# Firestore compound queries

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
  Object {
    "countryCode": "US",
    "createdAt": 1615080719516,
    "email": "alew14@gmail.com",
    "emailVerified": false,
    "firstName": "alejandro pereira",
    "gender": "Male",
    "id": "MrAPuFOFdqdlgMofaH2UomIFAU42",
    "lastLoginAt": 1615080719516,
    "lastName": "no last name",
    "photoURL": null,
    "userAuthenticated": true,
    "userAvailability": Object {
      "friday": Object {
        "afternoon": false,
        "evening": false,
        "morning": true,
      },
      "monday": Object {
        "afternoon": false,
        "evening": false,
        "morning": true,
      },
      "saturday": Object {
        "afternoon": false,
        "evening": false,
        "morning": true,
      },
      "sunday": Object {
        "afternoon": true,
        "evening": false,
        "morning": true,
      },
      "thursday": Object {
        "afternoon": false,
        "evening": false,
        "morning": true,
      },
      "tuesday": Object {
        "afternoon": false,
        "evening": false,
        "morning": true,
      },
      "wednesday": Object {
        "afternoon": false,
        "evening": false,
        "morning": true,
      },
    },
  }
```

*i need filter all users with `weekday contain "afternoon": true  OR  "evening": true OR morning": true ;`*

example insert monday and saturday return all user what contain "afternoon": true  OR  "evening": true OR morning": true in the field userAvailability

and not can...  try this

***usersfirestore.where( 'Monday' , "array-contains", true );***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to execute `OR` queries in Firestore. You will need to run multiple separate queries and combine the results together.